# Pattern matching in C++

Tags: c++, pattern-matching

I'm writing a compiler in C++ and as any compiler, it requires an extreme amount of pattern matching and dynamic casts. In languages like Rust, Haskell, and OCaml I can destruct a type easily, like:

```
match node {
    Binary{ left, right, operator } => { .. }
    _ => { .. }
}
```

In C++ the best I can do is:

```
if (auto bin = dynamic_cast<Binary*>(node)) { ... }
else if (...) { ... }
```

Which is really limited and ugly if you introduce smart pointers into the scene. For example if I need to match 2 things for something:

```
bool matched = false;
if (auto m1 = dynamic_cast<Foo*>(a)) {
    if (auto m2 = dynamic_cast<Bar*>(b)) {
        matched = true;
    }
}
if (!matched) {
    // This is because C++ does not allow you to declare two variables inside the condition...
}
```

I know about the Mach7 library but to be honest it seems awful as you need to write metadata for your structures (also as I've noticed it has quite a lot of bugs and limitations).

Is there a way to make these kind of matches more readable?

Comment: In a compiler you will probably have a definite set of possible types, so how about storing an `enum` value in the base class and switch on that?

Comment: @Quentin That would involve modifying the AST and setting every type to it's proper value. It would certainly be nicer, but still not a relatively nice solution.

Comment: There is no pattern matching in C++. If you need pattern matching, why do you use C++?

Comment: @Drop This is a language I'm very comfortable with. I know there is no "proper" pattern matching.

Comment: You might like my ACCU 2017 talk: [**"Implementing variant Visitation Using Lambdas"**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mqei4JJRQ7s), but it's only applicable to variant types.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo This is not your first talk that saves me ;)

Comment: It is ugly but it should be able to be made generalizeable: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cf817da1f02fff43

Comment: @NathanOliver Why the lambda?

Comment: @Quentin Not really sure.  I was just messing around and it was quick to write.  Pretty sure Something along `Hans` answer but using a tuple instead is probably the best approach.

Comment: Let's hope [pattern match](http://davidsankel.com/uncategorized/c-language-support-for-pattern-matching-and-variants/) will appear in c++20.

Answer (score 1):

The following seems to be a way to avoid the double if for two matches - and can easily be generalized:

```
template <class T1,class T2> struct castPairstruct : public std::pair<T1,T2> {
     operator bool() {return first && second;}
     castPairstruct<T1,T2>(T1 a,T2 b):std::pair<T1,T2>(a,b) {;}
};

template <class T1,class T2> castPairstruct<T1,T2> castPair(T1 a,T2 b){
    return castPairstruct<T1,T2>(a,b);
}
if (auto j=castPair(dynamic_cast<Foo*>(a),dynamic_cast<Bar*>(b)) {
```